# Most efficient values replacement from one data.table to another DT?

Tags: r, data.table

A couple of days ago I faced the following `data.table` issue about values assignment:

- reassign the values of a column (e.g. `DT1$type`) from another
  `data.table` column (e.g. `DT2$description`) based on the current value of the former
  (e.g. `DT1$type == DT2$id`).

I solved it in a classic way (i.e. using the `for` loop), but I've noticed that it takes a lot of time as the length of the `data.table` increases.

Therefore I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to obtain the same result?

My solution:

```
# Define the sample data.tables
DT1 <- data.table( user = c(rep(1,2), rep(2,3), rep(3,3)), 
                   type = c(1,2,1,4,2,3))

DT2 <- data.table( id = 1:4, 
                   description = c( "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"))

# set the keys
setkeyv(DT1,"user")
setkeyv(DT2, c("id","description"))

# Replace values
for ( i in 1:length(DT1$type) ) { 
  DT1$type[i] <- DT2[ DT2$id == DT1$type[i], description ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the keys on the columns you want to join, and then use the `[` data.table operator. For instance:

```
   DT1 <- data.table( user = c(rep(1,2), rep(2,3), rep(3,3)), 
               type = c(1,2,1,4,2,3))
   DT2 <- data.table( id = 1:4, 
               description = c( "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")) 
   setkeyv(DT1,"type")
   setkeyv(DT2,"id")
   res<-DT1[DT2,]
   #drop the first column
   res[,type:=NULL]
```